# Change Google apps script assigned to a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The simple question is, how do I change an already to a GSheets file assigned Google apps script ?

I'd like to replace the script that was assigned in the past by another updated script.

Comment: If `I'd like to replace the script that was assigned in the past by another updated script.` is the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet, how about using Google Apps Script API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects) When Google Apps Script API is used, the container-bound script can be managed. If using Google Apps Script API is not your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: Try opening the google apps script editor with Extension/Apps Script and ten open the desiired file and edit it by hand.  Since you are asking this as a simple question I assume that you don't wish to tackle the Apps Script  API wihich enables you to change them programatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of your input. Actually you're right, I've no experience in working with the API. I meanwhile did the workaround to copy the content of the updated version and paste it into the allocated script. But my original thought was to develop a script in a test environment and once it's working somehow to link it to the appropriate form or GSheet.